# how to translate page by current location language using MicrosoftTranslatorWidget

Tags: microsoft-translator

I am using MicrosoftTranslatorWidget to translate webpage,i want to translate webpage automatically by current location,Please help me.
Also you can share another api for translating webpage by current location.

```
<div id="MicrosoftTranslatorWidget" style="width: 400px; min-height: 20px; border-color: #404040; background-color: #A0A0A0;"><noscript><a href="">Translate this page</a><br />Powered by <a href="">Microsoft® Translator</a></noscript></div> <script type="text/javascript"> /* <![CDATA[ */ setTimeout(function() { var s = document.createElement("script"); s.type = "text/javascript"; s.charset = "UTF-8"; s.src = ((location && location.href && location.href.indexOf('https') == 0) ? "https://ssl.microsofttranslator.com" : "http://www.microsofttranslator.com" ) + "/ajax/v2/widget.aspx?mode=manual&from=en&layout=ts"; var p = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.documentElement; p.insertBefore(s, p.firstChild); }, 0); /* ]]> */ </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft no longer supports the translator widget.

To integrate Microsoft Translator in your website you have several options available:
The easiest and fastest one is to leverage Content Management Systems (CMS) that natively support the Translator API. For instance, Adobe Experience Manager (AEM) natively supports Microsoft Translator integration. From AEM you can integrate machine translation (with or without human post-editing added to the workflow) in your website development and deployment process. Learn more about AEM support for Microsoft Translator here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/aem.aspx

Similarly, with solutions like WeGlot, you can add machine translation based localization to many popular content management systems: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/customers.aspx#textsearch=weglot .

Finally, you can also decide to integrate into your custom CMS the Translator API for either off-line or real-time webpage translations. Visit the Microsoft Translator Getting Started page at http://www.aka.ms/TranslatorGettingStarted and follow the steps outlined on the webpage to subscribe to the API.